# Monomorphism definition counterexample

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

I just cannot understand why definition of monomorphism is this:

$$
\forall g_{1}, g_{2} : f \circ g_{1} = f \circ g_{2} \Rightarrow g_{1}=g_{2}
$$

if we consider injection as a special case of monomorphism we can simply build counterexample

[image]

Here we have two functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ that maps same set $c$ to $a$ differently, yet their composition with $f$ gives same results.

Meanwhile function $f$ is injective.

It is contradiction to what monomorphism definition says that for every possible pair of functions if their composition with $f$ equals, then those functions are equal, meanwhile they are not!

I find this definition to be accurate though:

$$
\text{ f is monomorphism} \iff \exists g_{1},g_{2},g_1\ne g_2 : f \circ g_1 = f \circ g_2
$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function $f$ is not injective.

Notice that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ and yet $x_1≠x_2$.

Maybe I'm misinterpreting something.

---

The main idea behind how the definition of monomorphism abstracts the definition of injection, is by noticing that an element of a set can be considered as a map from a set containing only one element $1 := \{*\}$, (doesn't matter what $*$ is) to your set.

So for instance if you have the set $\{1,2\}$, there are exactly two maps from $1$ to it, namely the map that sends $*$ to $1$ and the map that sends $*$ to $2$.

With this idea in mind, the definition of injectivity is just that of monomorphism but for the domain of the variables equal to the set $1$.

Namely, $f : X → Y$ is injective iff $∀ x,y : 1 → X.\ f ◦ x = f ◦ y \Rightarrow x = y$.

Comment: yeah, my bad.

In that video that I watch professor have surjection and injection messed up and I wrongly picked up function.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcT7CGPICzo&t=273s

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: my previous answer was partially wrong, so I'm just gonna leave this since Juliàn's answer perfectly address the point you are asking..

You are right saying that injections are a special case of monomorphisms, the problem is that your $f$ is not injective.
More generally (in a concrete category) it is true that left/right invertible $\implies$ injective/surjective $\implies$ monomorphism/epimorphism with the converse that in general does not hold.

Comment: I am confused by your first paragraph. You in fact confirm that injection is a special case of monomorphism ("every injection is also a monomorphism"). Your objection about monomorphisms not needing to be injective concerns the converse of that implication, and OP does not really show that in their question. OP's question / confusion is of a different nature, see for example Julián's answer.

Comment: Oh, my bad! I'm gonna correct it and upvote Juliàn's answer. which in fact address the point that the OP is asking much more than mine.